# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Feign Client for loadBalancing defined. Did you forget to include spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openfeign

I am getting exception:

```
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Feign Client for loadBalancing defined. Did you forget to include spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
    at com.hsbc.gbgcf.spartan.referencedatabase.UserRegistrationApplication.main(UserRegistrationApplication.java:57)
```

when executing my project. My pom.xml contains

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

I am using feign client in other projects of mine as well without any additional dependency of ribbon and these are working with same spring-boot version 2.0.8

I have referred other stack overflow link for same issue and they have asked to add additional dependency of ribbon. I have tried adding same in my pom.xml but it didn't helped.

FeignClient interface is,

```
@FeignClient(value = "user-service", decode404 = true)
public interface UserFeignClient {

    @PostMapping("/do-something")
    void doSomething();
}
```

Main class code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"test.user"})
public class UserRegistrationApplication{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserFeignClient userFeignClient = applicationContext.getBean(UserFeignClient.class);
        userFeignClient.doSomething();
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext));
    }
}
```

I am using Sprint Boot version 2.0.8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to decide, which client load balancer to use: (1)**Spring Cloud Loadbalancer** or (2)**Ribbon**.

> Spring Cloud Loadbalancer is a generic abstraction that can do the work that we used to do with Netflix’s Ribbon project. Spring Cloud still supports Netflix Ribbon, but Netflix Ribbons days are numbered, like so much else of the Netflix microservices stack, so we’ve provided an abstraction to support an alternative

Check here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/spring-tips-spring-cloud-loadbalancer

(1) **Spring Cloud Load Balancer**:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    loadbalancer:
       ribbon:
        enable: false

# And... inform the "url" attribute at FeignClient
@FeignClient(name = "student", url = "student")
```

(2) **Ribbon**:
Add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>

# And (optionally)... @application.yaml

   spring:
      cloud:
        loadbalancer:
           ribbon:
            enable: true
```

Comment: What's the url = "student" mean? Where is this student defined?

Comment: `student ` is the Microservice name you want to invoke which is registered at Discovery client.

Answer (score 27):

For me, the problem was not include `url` parameter in `@FeignClient` annotation:

```
@FeignClient(name = "microservice-common", url = "${microservice-common.url}")
```

Comment: Wow. It works like a charm. You saved my day. It is basic but important trick when we don't want to import Netflix-ribbon load balancer dependency to our project

Comment: Worked! I had 2 feign clients, one had the url attribute, the other didn't. The stack trace however highlighted the wrong client. So in summary, if someone has multiple  clients, they should make sure all of them have the url attribute in the @FeignClient annotation.

Answer (score 5):

> Ribbon

Requires Spring Boot Version >= 2.0.0.RELEASE and < 2.4.0-M1

Answer (score 4):

Use `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` dependency instead of `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon`.

Answer (score 1):

Add **ServiceName**(i.e feignName) with its URL in your feignClient interface.

```
@FeignClient(name = "user-service", url = "feignUrl", decode404 = true)
public interface UserFeignClient {
    @PostMapping("/do-something")
    void doSomething();
}
```

Feign Client is tool for making easier call to Rest-Api of other service where as Ribbon is used mostly for load balancing.

If you want to use ribbon

1. Add this dependency to your pom.xml

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```

2. FeignClient interface

   ```
   @FeignClient(name="ServiceName")
   @RibbonClient(name="ServiceName")
   ```
3. configure your **application.properties** like given below

> ServiceName.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8000,http://localhost:8001

Comment: Thanks @Harshal for comment. I tried adding ribbon dependency in pom but no luck. I added hystrix dependency and it worked, as hystrix internally uses loadBalancer.